# ToView appearing behind FromView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view

I'm doing a fairly simple segue by presenting the next view controller with a custom transition animation.

Essentially, the transition creates the toView off the screen and then slides it over the fromView from the right, while the fromView slides off the left at a slightly slower speed. The dismissing transition does the opposite.

My problem is after dismissing the toView to go back to the fromView, when I trigger the segue again, the toView is sliding under the fromView instead of over. This doesn't happen on the first transition, but happens for everyone of them after.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it's doing this, let alone how to fix it. Any help would be awesome.

segue code:

`let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: kOnboardingSignupStoryboard, bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: kOnboardingErrorIdentifier) as! OnboardingErrorViewController
            vc.transitioningDelegate = self
            vc.errorMessage = kErrorIncorrectPin
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`

dismiss code:

`dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

transition extension:

```
extension OnboardingErrorViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return FromRightDeck()
}

func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return DismissFromRightDeck()
}
```

[Gif of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZDbm.gif)

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: Also can you attach a small gif showing what is happening?

Comment: I've added my segue and dismiss code, @RakeshaShastri I'll try and get a gif of what happening

Comment: Errrr... you are presenting it, but it slides from the right and not the bottom? o.O

Comment: Yeah that's right, I have an extension on the View Controller that uses the custom transition animation instead of the standard one.

Comment: Can you add the transition delegate code?

Comment: @Sam No worries, it's pretty simple, but I've added it in

Comment: Can you show the method DismissFromRightDeck?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I managed to solve it after diving into the animation code. Initially I didn't think this would have anything to do with it, as it works fine the first time and every other time I use the animation. However, there was an errant line of code pushing to toView z position which I was using in testing, that was causing this issue.